# Using LINQ .Distinct() with DateTime - Selecting only the first instance of a date

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I use EF and LINQ in my MVC 3 web app.

I have a query like this

```
var dates = timetableEvents.GroupBy(x => x.DateTimeStart).Distinct();
```

`x.DateTimeStart` are date in this format:

```
23/01/2013 12:47:13
23/01/2013 14:00:10
23/01/2013 16:15:00
24/01/2013 02:05:00
24/01/2013 04:55:05
25/01/2013 06:00:00
```

I need to have the filter which select only the first instance of a date.

How to do it?

```
23/01/2013
24/01/2013
25/01/2013
```

Comment: Can you have them as strings?

Comment: Please guy add a comment if you down vote so I can improve my question. If you think this question is to much trivial, please ignore it

Comment: @GibboK Maybe it would help if your post actually included a question, with a question-mark?

Comment: Thanks Espo for your comment... I have updated my question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Can you try

```
  var dates = timetableEvents.GroupBy(x => x.DateTimeStart.Date).Distinct();
```